# Internet Explorer doesn't know how to add options tag to a select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html-select

Im facing a problem with jQuery in the Internet Explorer 7 and 8, while trying to add a option to a existing select:

```js
var s = document.getElementById("category");
s.options.add(select_option);
```

But IE just says:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

and points to `s.options.add(select_option);`

Comment: Are you sure `s` is actually a reference to a `<select>` element? IE does support the `add()` method of the `options` collection.

Comment: then you should have $("#category") instead of document.getElementById and I thing @fearofawhackplanet first option would be the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the element with id "category" is actually a `<select>`, the easiest way is the the following time-honoured code for adding an option to a select list in any browser:

```
var s = document.getElementById("category");
s.options[s.options.length] = new Option("Option text", "optionValue");
```

Comment: +1, although there's no reason *element.options.add()* wouldn't work unless you were trying to migrate an option element from a different document, but that would give a different error.

Comment: @Andy: Yes indeed, `s.options.add(new Option("text", "value"))` would work just as well. My version is what I used to use when coding for IE 4 and Netscape 4 (which didn't have the `add()` method). I think it worked in Netscape 3 too.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('#category').append('<option value="foo" selected="selected">Foo</option>');
```

or

```
var options = $('#category').attr('options');
options[options.length] = new Option('Foo', 'foo', true, true);
```

Comment: var options = $('#category').attr('options'); really?? that works?

Comment: Why **wouldn't** that work?  `<select>` DOM elements always have an "options" attribute.

Comment: @Diego: jQuery's `attr()` function actually maps to a property name where possible.  It may be confusing, but `$(element).attr('options')` is the equivalent of `element.options`.

Comment: select elements have tags "option" as inner html, didn't know it was also an attribute

Answer (score 1):

This soulution is working fine under IE8 - copied from MIcrosoft forum -

"I assume you already got the answer you needed, but for anyone else who finds this post when searching this problem (like I did), here's the solution that worked for me.  All it took was setting the properties on opt AFTER adding it to the options collection.  I also found that MSDN's page on the add function (for the options collection) explicitly states that for IE, the properties must be set after the option is added, but most of the examples I found online don't do it that way.  I think your way may have worked in older versions of IE."

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');  
select.options.add(opt);       
opt.innerHTML = 'Foo';  
opt.value = 'Bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

Should the `add()` call not be on the `select` element, rather than the collection of options?  I.e.:

```
s.add(select_option);
```